# Algorithm for generating an array with a subarray sum of zero

Tags: python, c++, arrays, algorithm

I am trying to randomly generate an array of integers of range between -10^7 to 10^7 such that there exists a sub-array with a sum of zero.

For example : 7 6 4 8 -4 -8

1<=Size of array<=10^5

I am able to do it using brute-force but it is taking a lot of time as I have to generate very big such arrays. Is there any efficient way of achieving this using python or c++?

Edit: Actually I want to generate a lot of such arrays with different scenarios. I am generating these arrays as testcases for a problem to determine whether any given array of positive and negative integers contain a sub-array with zero sum.

Tried brute force code:

```
import random
N = random.randint(10,100)
mylist = []
for i in xrange(1,N):
  mylist.append(random.randint(-100,100))
list2 = [1,-1]
mylist = mylist[1:N-2] + list2 + mylist[N-2:N]
print mylist
```

So I have to manually tweak it a lot.

Thanks!

Comment: One quick hack would be to ensure that you include a zero as one of the elements and randomly generate all other elements. Then you are always guaranteed to have a sub-array of size 1 with the sum of zero.

Comment: @wookie919 Thanks. Actually that is one of the case. I want to generate a lot of such arrays with different scenarios. I am generating these arrays as testcases for a problem to determine whether any given array of positive and negative integers contain a sub-array with zero sum

Comment: What is the purpose of generating this list of integers? How long a list are you generating? Using random numbers and hoping that some sequence will be "zero" in a long list with large span between min and max seems rather optimistic, so "cheating" in some way is certainly the best way to guarantee it happens.

Comment: Could you share the code for which you are `able to do it using brute-force`? It may help potential answerers.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Thanks! Purpose of generating such list is to prepare a question for a candidate to solve and to check his programming skills.Actually I have prepared many such cases but yes was thinking whether there is some hack of generating various tricky scenarios with big numbers.

Comment: Generate a random array and then pick a random subset. Add the negative of its sum to your array. Not sure what the distribution of this is. Just a suggestion.

Comment: So take a list with small numbers and do ´(x * 1941212119) % 123123457´ or something like that?

Comment: @DavidRobinson I have shared my brute-force code. I manually making a lot of changes to it that is why I am looking for some efficient way.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Thanks a nice way out!

Comment: You could generate any array with random numbers, calculate their sum (if there is 0, continue, if not, add the corresponding needed element to be sure that sum 0, ex: if its generated 1 2 -5, you need to add 2 to have sum 0), and generate again random elements to put at the beginning and at the end until reaching expected size.

Comment: Of course, unless the programmer is a complete idiot, there is no difference between finding a sub-array that has a zero sum when it has large numbers than when it has small numbers [unless there is overflow in the summation].

Comment: @NetVipeC Thanks your approach is good. I am trying to think a solution over your approach.

Comment: This will be a very large number of arrays. Late enough that they can only be generated on demand. As an example, you will have a large number of reflective type arrays of the form of `[[-1,1],[-2,2],[-2,-1,1,2],etc]` Just that pattern is millions of arrays.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Yes the whole point is that the candidate should solve the question in linear time. Brute force code of candidate should fail on large arrays.

Comment: You'd better not try to hire me then... As I don't know (without looking it up on the web, which presumably you aren't expecting people to do).

Comment: @MatsPetersson question is to detect whether a given array has a subarray sum of zero which will be given to the candidate. This question is my problem which I am facing while generating some testcases for the problem.

Comment: @gmfreak I don't think the code that you have given above classifies as "brute force". In fact, it's no different from inserting a single zero somewhere. True brute force would be to randomly generate ALL elements, then check if a sub-array exists that sum to zero, and if not, rinse and repeat.

Comment: @wookie919 Yes you are right. Actually I realized that one way or other inserting a zero sum subset is the only helpful trick for this scenario. Any kind of check or iteration over check would be very expensive and might become a brute-force. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on how **random** you want your array to be. Like some of the commenters mentioned, you can always include a zero and are thus guaranteed to have a subarray with sum of zero. I thought it would be helpful to your eventual solution, so I want to mention that you can check if an array has a subarray with sum of zero in O(N^2) time.

```
def array_has_zerosubarray( A ):
    for _begin in xrange(0,len(A)-1):
       for _end in xrange(_begin+1,len(A)):
           sum = 0
           for ai in range(_begin,_end):
               sum = sum + A[ai]
           if sum==0:
              return True
    return False
```

Comment: Thanks. It can be achieved in O(N) time.